# sub domain via apache

Tags: apache-2.2

**UPDATE 1:**

I now have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.companyname.com
DocumentRoot /www/html/www.companyname.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.companyname.com
DocumentRoot /www/html/www.companyname.com/test/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which does not work when I type into the browser

```
http://test.companyname.com
```

However, when I restart apache, I get a message saying

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Tue Apr 05 10:49:48 2011] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

How do I configure apache so I can have many sub domains along with my main domain?

for example, google has

www.google.com
mail.google.com
docs.google.com

how do I do the same, but get the sub domain to go to a different directory and or web page on the website?

We use a LAMP configuration on RedHat linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up multiple `VirtualHost`s with a different `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` for each.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com/
    # ... other directives ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com/
    # ... other directives ...
<VirtualHost>
```

I encourage you to have a look at your existing config files (which are under `/etc/httpd/` on RedHat, I believe), and have also to have a look at [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/).

Comment: This does not seem to work.  Do I need to restart apache for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Yes, I had to restart, but when I do and even though it restart fine, I get a link broken message when I try to go to the website.

Comment: Please see update 1 in original question.

Comment: Have you set up your A-records correctly to point to your server? What **does** happen when you type the address into your browser (i.e. more specific than it "does not work")?

Answer (score 0):

If someone types http://sub1.example.com then it will point to http://example.com/sub1/.

Solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ftp|mail).example.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).example.com 
RewriteRule (.*) /subd_%1/$1 [L]
```

Check your .htaccess file.

Your question was not that bad, just need to know what you used for serving.

Comment: this should prove helpful for you as well...
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Please see update 1 in original question.